# Arquitetura de Computadores - Transistores

Tags: arquitetura-computadores

Eu não entendi ao certo, cada transistor pode estar ligado ou desligado (0-1), mas cada transistor então equivale a 1 *byte* ou a 1 *bit*?

Então se cada transistor equivale 1 *byte* então se eu tiver 8 transistores seria *bytes* então teria 64 *bits*?

Talvez seja uma pergunta bem simples de se responder, mas estou estudando arquitetura de computadores vendo como realmente trabalha a fundo.

Comment: 1 byte é igual 8 bits. 32 bits(4 bytes) e 64 bits(8 bytes).

Comment: Sim, mas a pergunta é sobre em sí o quanto equivale um transistor suporta, se é 1bit ou 1byte... Não quero ser grosso.

Comment: Você poderia ser mais grosso do mundo,mas a educação e profissionalismo vem primeiro. 1 bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trecho do livro Santana,Edu - Arquitetura de Computadores. Disponibilizado pela Universidade Federal da Paraíba: http://producao.virtual.ufpb.br/books/edusantana/introducao-a-arquitetura-de-computadores-livro/livro/

## 1.6. O Transistor

O transistor é um componente eletrônico criado na década de 1950. Ele é o responsável pela revolução da eletrônica na década de 1960. Através dele foi possível desenvolver sistemas digitais extremamente pequenos. Todas funcionalidades de um computador são internamente executadas pela composição de milhões de transistores. Desde operações lógicas e aritméticas, até o armazenamento de dados em memórias (a exceção do disco rígido, CD, DVD e fitas magnéticas), tudo é feito pelos transistores.

Os primeiros eram fabricados na escala de micrômetros 10-6 metros). Daí surgiram os termos microeletrônica e micro-tecnologia. Depois disso deu-se início a uma corrida tecnológica para se desenvolver transistores cada vez mais rápidos, menores e mais baratos. Essa revolução dura até hoje, mas foi mais forte nas décadas de 1980 e 1990. Foi emocionante acompanhar a disputa entre as empresas norte-americadas Intel e AMD para dominar o mercado de computadores pessoais. A cada 6 meses um novo processador era lançado por um delas, tomando da concorrente a posição de processador mais rápido do mercado. Poucos eram aqueles consumidores que conseguiam se manter a atualizados com tantos lançamentos.

O princípio básico é utilizar a eletrônica (corrente elétrica, resistência e tensão) para representar dados e depois poder executar operações com eles. A forma mais fácil de fazer isso foi primeiramente limitar os dados a apenas dois tipos. Zero e um. O sistema de numeração binário é muito mais fácil de representar com dispositivos eletrônicos do que o decimal, por exemplo. O transistor possui dois estados. Ou ele está carregado, ou está descarregado, assim como uma pilha. Isso facilmente pode ser mapeado para o bit 1 (carregado) e o bit (0). O revolucionário, diferente de uma pilha, foi possibilitar que esse estado pudesse ser mudado eletronicamente a qualquer momento e de forma muito rápida.

Assim, com 8 transistores em paralelo, eu posso representar, por exemplo um número de 8 bits. Posso mudar seus valores mudando suas cargas, e posso ler seus valores chegando se cada um possui, ou não carga. Esse é o princípio básico de construção de uma memória.

De forma semelhante, é possível integrar transistores para que os mesmos executem operações lógicas e aritméticas. As portas lógicas estudadas por você em Introdução à Computação são todas fabricadas utilizando transistores.

Quanto menores são os transistores, mais dados podem ser armazenados por área. Ao mesmo tempo, transistores menores guardam menos carga. Isso torna mais rápido o processo de carregamento e descarregamento, que, por consequência, torna o processamento e armazenamento de dados muito mais rápidos também.

Com a evolução da nanoeletrônica, os transistores são tão pequenos que possibilitou a construção de memórias de 1GB (um giga byte) do tamanho da unha da mão de um adulto. Para ser ter uma ideia, 1 Giga é a abreviação de 109, ou seja, um bilhão. Um byte são 8 bits. Então, uma memória de 1GB possui, pelo menos, 8 bilhões de transistores. Os processadores também se tornaram bastante velozes com a miniaturização dos transistores. Os processadores atuais trabalham na frequência de GHz (Giga Hertz), ou seja, na casa de bilhões de ciclos por segundo (diferente de operações por segundo). Isso é muito rápido!

**Figura 1.3. Estrutura de um transistor tipo MOSFET**

[image: Estrutura de um transistor tipo MOSFET]

Na Figura 1.3, “Estrutura de um transistor tipo MOSFET” anterior é apresentada a estrutura de um transistor MOSFET. Esse transistor é o mais utilizado para se construir sistemas eletrônicos digitais, como os computadores. O nome vem da abreviação de “Metal-Oxide Semiconductor Field-Effect Transistor”. Vamos ver o que significa cada palavra dessas, e isso nos ajudará a conhecer um pouco mais o MOSFET e sua relevância. O termo MOS (“Metal-Oxide Semiconductor”) vem dos materiais utilizados para compor um MOSFET, que são principalmente, óxido metálico e semicondutor.

Semicondutores são materiais que possuem propriedades que nem os permitem classificar como condutor, nem como isolante. Em algumas condições ele age como um isolante, e em outras, como um condutor. O semicondutor mais utilizado em transistores é o silício (símbolo Si na Tabela Periódica). Em condições ambientes, o silício age como um isolante, mas se misturado a outros materiais, ele pode se tornar um condutor até a intensidade desejada.

> O Silício se tornou tão importante que modificou toda uma região da
>   Califórnia nos Estados Unidos na década de 1950, tornando-a uma das
>   mais promissoras do mundo até hoje. Essa região abrigou e abriga as
>   mais importantes empresas do ramo de projeto de computadores, como
>   Intel, AMD, Dell, IBM e Apple, e depois de softwares que iriam
>   executar nesses computadores, como Microsoft, Oracle e Google. Essa
>   região é chamada de Vale do Silício.

No transistor da Figura 1.3, “Estrutura de um transistor tipo MOSFET” o cinza claro representa um cristal de silício que foi dopado com cargas negativas. Já o cinza escuro, representa a parte que foi dopada com cargas positivas.

Na situação normal (ver Figura 1.4, “Abertura e fechamento da porta do transistor tipo MOSFET”) uma corrente elétrica aplicada no Dreno consegue percorrer o estreito canal negativo e seguir até a Fonte. Nessa condição dizemos que o transistor está ativo. Porém, se for aplicada uma tensão negativa na Porta, as cargas positivas da região p serão atraídas para mais próximo da Porta, e isso irá fechar o canal por onde passava a corrente elétrica. Nesse caso, dizemos que o transistor está inativo.

**Figura 1.4. Abertura e fechamento da porta do transistor tipo MOSFET**

[image: Abertura e fechamento da porta do transistor tipo MOSFET]

Por que isso tudo nos interessa? Quando o transistor está ativo, ele pode ser visto com o valor 1, e quando inativo, ele pode ser visto com o valor 0. Assim, temos a menor memória possível de ser construída. Quando quisermos que ela guarde o valor 1, basta desligar a tensão da Porta e aplicar uma corrente no Dreno. Já quando quisermos que ele armazene o valor 0, precisamos aplicar uma corrente na Porta e fechar o canal. Então, uma memória de 8 bilhões de bits, pode ser elaborada com 8 bilhões de transistores como esses.

Agora conhecemos o primeiro aspecto que faz dos transistores essenciais para o entendimento do computador. Eles são usados para a construção de memórias. Memórias feitas a base de transistores são chamadas também de Memórias de Estado Sólido. Mas há outras, não tão eficientes e miniaturizadas, como memórias ópticas e magnéticas. O importante percebermos é que quanto menores pudermos construir esses transistores, melhor. O processo de abertura e fechamento do canal não é instantâneo. Ele leva um curtíssimo tempo, mas quando somados os tempos de todos os bilhões de transistores, ele passa a se tornar relevante. Quanto menor ele for, mais estreito é o canal e, portanto, mais rápido ele liga e desliga, da mesma forma, menor será a distância entre o Dreno e a Fonte, levando também menos tempo para os elétrons deixarem o Dreno em direção à fonte. Isso tudo fará a memória mais rápida. Transistores pequenos também possibilitam que mais dados sejam armazenados por área. É por isso que hoje enormes capacidades de armazenamento são disponíveis em dispositivos tão reduzidos, como são os exemplos de pen-drives e cartões de memória.

Os transistores também são usados para executar operações lógicas e aritméticas. A carga retirada de um transistor pode servir para alimentar um outro e que, se combinados de forma correta, podem executar as operações lógicas básicas, E, OU, NÃO e as aritméticas, adição, subtração, divisão e multiplicação. Com isso, os transistores não apenas podem ser utilizados para armazenar dados, mas como executar operações lógicas e aritméticas sobre esses dados. Isso é fantástico e vem revolucionado todo o mundo. Não só na Ciência da Computação, mas como também em todas áreas do conhecimento. O que seria da humanidade hoje sem o computador? Sem o telefone celular? Sem os satélites?

Answer (score -1):

Achei essas informações do livro de Santana muito boas, obrigado pela leitura. Fiquei com uma duvida pois segundo o trecho do livro é necessário aplicar uma corrente na porta para ter o bit 0 isso significa que a nível fisico 1 bit teria 5v e 0 bit seria 0.5v ?

Comment: Você usou o campo de resposta para fazer um comentário. Você poderá postar comentários quando tiver [um pouco mais de pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor utilize o campo de resposta somente para postar uma solução ao problema de que a pergunta trata. Quanto sua dúvida a voltagem operacional de um processador não há um valor padrão, para cada modelo deve consultar o manual para conhecer os seus modos de operação e então para cada modo conhecer  a sua voltagem e corrente operacional.